# `ld` adds code to `0x1000` instead of `0x0`

Tags: ld, gnu-assembler, linker-scripts

I've the following files:

`boot.s`

```
.section code_section
code:
    jmp code

.section boot_magic_section
boot_magic:
    .word 0xaa55
```

`linker_script.ld`

```
SECTIONS {
    beginning : {
        boot.o(code_section)
        . += 510;
        boot.o(boot_magic_section)
    } = 0
    .bss : {
        *(COMMON)
    }
    rest : {
        *(.note.gnu.property)
    }
}
```

I compiled the `boot.s` with: `as -o boot.o boot.s`. Now if I do `ld -T linker_script.ld -o boot.bin boot.o && objdump -D boot.bin`, I'm getting the following output:

```
boot.bin:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section beginning:

0000000000000000 <code>:
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0 <code>
    ...

0000000000000200 <boot_magic>:
 200:   55                      push   %rbp
 201:   aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)

Disassembly of section rest:

0000000000000208 <rest>:
 208:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
 20a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 20c:   20 00                   and    %al,(%rax)
 20e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 210:   05 00 00 00 47          add    $0x47000000,%eax
 215:   4e 55                   rex.WRX push %rbp
 217:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
 219:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
 21b:   c0 04 00 00             rolb   $0x0,(%rax,%rax,1)
 21f:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
 221:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 223:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 225:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 227:   00 02                   add    %al,(%rdx)
 229:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
 22b:   c0 04 00 00             rolb   $0x0,(%rax,%rax,1)
    ...
```

as you can see, my `code` section is in the beginning. But if I do `hexdump boot.bin -x`, I'm getting the following output:

```
0000000    457f    464c    0102    0001    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000010    0002    003e    0001    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000020    0040    0000    0000    0000    12e0    0000    0000    0000
0000030    0000    0000    0040    0038    0002    0040    0006    0005
0000040    0001    0000    0004    0000    1000    0000    0000    0000
0000050    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000060    0238    0000    0000    0000    0238    0000    0000    0000
0000070    1000    0000    0000    0000    0004    0000    0004    0000
0000080    1208    0000    0000    0000    0208    0000    0000    0000
0000090    0208    0000    0000    0000    0030    0000    0000    0000
00000a0    0030    0000    0000    0000    0008    0000    0000    0000
00000b0    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
*
0001000    feeb    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
...
```

Why does it start at `0x1000` and not from `0x0`? How can I let my assembly code start from `0x0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found out what those first 0x1000 bytes are thanks to `hexdump boot.bin -c`:

```
0000000 177   E   L   F 002 001 001  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000010 002  \0   >  \0 001  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020   @  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 330 022  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
...
```

It looks like that it's the ELF header. I was probably missing `--oformat binary` for `ld` and the only solution seems to be stripping the binary.